# How to call api using fetch in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
 const login: SubmitHandler<ILoginValues> = async ({email, password}) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/api/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        await setGenericPassword(email, password, CREDENTIALS_STORAGE_OPTIONS);
        setUser({isLoggedIn: true, hasSessionExpired: false});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.setToast({message: 'Login failed', visible: true});
    }
  };
```

I am creating a login flow in react native using java spring rest api. My Api is running at address http://localhost:8082/api/v1/users how can I get the data from client side using fetch in React native and also store the JWT token in client side.

Comment: What's wrong? It's there an error?

Answer (score -2):

You can perform the login request when the form is submitted. Than wait for the response and save the jwt in local storage. Than login the user into the logged in ui.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form-id")
form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) =>{ 
e.prevetDefault() your code })
```